# Prove that if $p: X \rightarrow Y$ is a $2$-fold covering projection, then $p$ is a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove that if $p: X \rightarrow Y$ is a $2$-fold covering projection, then $p$ is a quotient map.

By the definition of a covering projection, $p$ is both continuous and surjective. We have $p^{-1} (Y) = Y' \coprod Y''$ where $Y'$ and $Y''$ are homeomorphic to $Y$. So for any open set $A \coprod B$ in $X$, we have that $p|_{Y'}(A)$ and $p|_{Y''}(B)$ are open in $Y$.

Let $U$ be a subset of $Y$. If $p^{-1}(U)$ is open, then $p^{-1}(U) = U' \coprod U''$ for some open $U' \in Y'$ and $U'' \in Y''$. By the definition of a covering map, we have that $p|_{Y'}(U')$ and $p|_{Y''}(U'')$ are open in $Y$. But since $p|_{Y'}(U') = U = pl_{Y''}(U'')$, we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: An open continuous onto map is a quotient map.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks a lot. So is my answer right or wrong?

Comment: The most interesting cases of covering maps are those for which the covering space $X$ is connected. In those cases, we do not have the relation $p^{-1}(Y) = Y' \coprod Y''$ with $Y'$ and $Y''$ homeomorphic to $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a $2$-fold covering projection we do not necessarily have $p^{-1}[Y] = Y' \coprod Y''$ as you say. So we cannot base an argument on that. Also in general we cannot say that for any $U \subset Y$ we can say that its inverse image is such a disjoint union. So let's reason more generally.

We do know that an open continuous surjective map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map: suppose $f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X$ for some $A \subset Y$. Then as $f$ is open, $f[f^{-1}[A]]$ is open in $Y$ but as $f$ is surjective this set just equals $A$ again. So $A$ is open in $Y$ (and continuity gives that if $A$ is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X$, so we have a quotient map).

Now any covering map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ (covering projection) is a [local homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism): if $x \in X$, let $U$ be an evenly covered neighbourhood of $f(x)$; this means that $f^{-1}[U] = \cup_{i \in I} U_i$, where the union is of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$ (we could also write $f^{-1}[U] = \coprod_{i \in I} U_i$ if one likes) such that for all $i$, $f|_{U_i}: U_I \rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism between $U_i$ and $U$. Then the $U_i$ that contains $x \in f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}] \subset f^{-1}[U]$ shows that $f$ is a local homeomorphism at $x$.

And any local homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an open map: let $O \subset X$ be open, let $y \in f[O]$, so write $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in O$. Then let $U_x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that $f|_{U_x}$ is a homeomorphism between $U_x$ and $f[U_x]$ and $f[U_x]$ open in $Y$. Then $V_x = U_x \cap O$ is open (both in $X$ and $U_x$) so $f[V_x] = f[O] \cap f[U_x]$ is open in $Y$ ($f$ is a homeomorphism on $U_x$ so an open map on that domain) and witnesses that $y$ has an open neighbourhood that is a subset of $f[O]$, so every $y \in f[O]$ is an interior point and $f[O]$ is open.

So indeed every covering map that is surjective (which is often part of the definition) is a quotient map, it is even a local homeomorphism so open. Which is quite a bit stronger! We do not need that it is 2-fold, or even $n$-fold for any $n$ etc.